# How can I access the (this) attribute inside onSelect event of persian datepicker jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have multiple instances of a class inside the dom. like the example below.

```
let element = $(".datepicker-birthdate").pDatepicker({
    observer: true,
    altField: '.observer-example-alt',
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    initialValue: false,
    autoClose: true,
    calendar:{
        'persian': {
            'locale': 'fa',
            'showHint': false
        },
        'gregorian': {
            'locale': 'en',
            'showHint': false
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (date, e){
        e: is undefine here also
        element: is the last instance of .datepicker-birthdate
    }
});
```

the element always return the last instance of date picker, however i want to access the one that I have changes.
Does anyone has a solution around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `onSelect` function does not receive the event or the element as parameters, which seems to be the case given your description of them being `undefined` in the question, then you can instead manually loop through the elements in the class and instantiate the date picker on them individually. This allows you to maintain the `this` reference within the `select` handler function:

```js
$(".datepicker-birthdate").each(function() {
  let $datePicker = $(this);
  $datePicker.pDatepicker({
    observer: true,
    altField: '.observer-example-alt',
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    initialValue: false,
    autoClose: true,
    calendar: {
      'persian': {
        'locale': 'fa',
        'showHint': false
      },
      'gregorian': {
        'locale': 'en',
        'showHint': false
      }
    },
    onSelect: function(date) {
      // use $datepicker as needed here...
      $datePicker.addClass('foo');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact the library should provide the this object inside onSelect event, while they did not, perhaps using a foreach loop on the class as Rory McCrossan described would be the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

step 1: open the persian-datepicker.min.js

step2:
replace

```
e.model.options.onSelect(t);
```

with

```
e.model.options.onSelect(t, e);
```

step3:
after:

```
$('').persianDatepicker({
        onSelect: function (formattedDate, e) {

           console.log($("#" + e.id).val());

        }
});
```